# Keep getting last value in for loop

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get all the values in the variable roomnum, but the last value of roomnum keeps showing up. However, when I tried to print roomnum the values show up correctly. I'm not quite sure where the problem lies.

```
roomnum = request.POST.getlist('polygon-names')
            print(roomnum)

for k,v in unique_keys.items():
                if category_in_excel == "Material":
                    color_cell_format = workbook.add_format({'font_color': 'black', 'bg_color': v['color']})
                    color_cell_format.set_align('center')
                    worksheet.write(row + 1, col, k, cell_format)
                    worksheet.write(row + 1, col + 1, v['color'], color_cell_format)
                    worksheet.write(row + 1, col + 2, convert_quantity_from_mm_squared_to(units, v['initialArea'], precision), cell_format)
                    worksheet.write(row + 1, col + 3, units, cell_format)
                    worksheet.write(row + 1, col + 4, ",".join(v['pages']), cell_format)
                else:
                    for i in roomnum:
                        print(i)
                        worksheet.write(row + 1, col, i, cell_format)
                    worksheet.write(row + 1, col + 1, convert_quantity_from_mm_squared_to(units, v['initialArea'], precision), cell_format)
                    worksheet.write(row + 1, col + 2, units, cell_format)
                    worksheet.write(row + 1, col + 3, ",".join(v['pages']), cell_format)
```

Terminal when I print out the i value in roomnum: [image: Terminal when I print out roomnum:]

Values that I get in excel worksheet: [image]

As shown, the value keeps repeating for Polygon 3, when it should be Polygon 1,2,3. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: shouldn't that be row + 1 then row + 2 and so on

Comment: The value of **row** doesn't change anywhere in this code